# Could not get mongodb connectivity with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

**I have tried this in nodejs but  i am getting undefined as output in my console**

```
// Connect using a MongoClient instance
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const test = require("assert");
// Connection url
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
// Database Name
const dbName = "test";
// Connect using MongoClient
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url);
mongoClient.connect(function (err, client) {
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  try {
    db.collection("employeeDetails")
      .find({})
      .toArray(function (err, res) {
        console.log(res);
      });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  } finally {
    client.close();
  }
});
```

**I have data in mongodb :**
[image]

How do i get my employee details in my console Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the connection before getting the results. If you print `err` inside `toArray()` along with result, you will see below error -

```
MongoExpiredSessionError: Cannot use a session that has ended
```

This is happening because the `db.collection("employeeDetails")...` is getting called but waits for results in callback, till then it moves ahead and since after that statement you are exiting `try-catch`, you enter into `finally` which closes the session. When the `db.collection...` call is processed, this session is already ended and you see this error.

You can use async await. Modify your code as below -

```
// Connect using a MongoClient instance
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const test = require("assert");
// Connection url
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
// Database Name
const dbName = "test";
// Connect using MongoClient
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url);
mongoClient.connect(async function (err, client) {
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  try {
    const result = await db.collection('employeeDetails').find({}).toArray();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  } finally {
    client.close();
  }
});
```

In the line `mongoClient.connect(async function (err, client)..` we're using async before the callback function and later inside, we can just get the result using -

```
const result = await db.collection('employeeDetails').find({}).toArray();
```

After this `console.log` will print your results correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me
`let result = await collection(collection).find(query).toArray()`